# Display product price without loading whole product

Tags: product, attributes, price

I have built a widget which shows the price of a product. This widget can be used on a CMS page.

To obtain the price of the product, the product is loaded and then the price is obtained with `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getPriceHtml()` function.

When a CMS page contains multiple price widgets, a product is fetched from the database for each widget. To minimize loading times, I would like to reduce the data which is loaded for a widget to the minimum required to render the price.

What is the minimum set of attributes to render product price?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer the question, but I think you can get this information, by hooking into `Varien_Object::__call` method and check for `$this instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and if it is a `get`, just output the `$key`